# How i make animation for radar raster like a rainviewer on mapbox

Tags: javascript, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-api-rastertiles

I'm using rainviewer tiles for the radar data.

https://tilecache.rainviewer.com/v2/radar/1568251200/256/{z}/{x}/{y}/3/0_0.png

And i want update the tiles raster with the timestamp to make animation for a radar, like https://rainviewer.com.

I get the timestamps from this url
https://tilecache.rainviewer.com/api/maps.json

I apologize for the bad English

```
function update_radar(){
    $.getJSON("https://tilecache.rainviewer.com/api/maps.json",     function(data) {
    map.removeLayer("rainviewer");
    map.removeSource("rainviewer");
    map.addSource("rainviewer", {
        type: "raster",
        tiles: [
            getPath(data[data.length - 1])
        ],
        tileSize: 256
    });
    map.addLayer({
        id: "rainviewer",
        type: "raster",
        source: "rainviewer",
        paint: {
            "raster-opacity": 1
        },
        minzoom: 0,
        maxzoom: 12
    });
    });
}

function getPath(time) {
    return "https://tilecache.rainviewer.com/v2/radar/" + time + "/256/{z}/{x}/{y}/3/0_0.png";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add a layer for each source initially, then set them all to be hidden and enable the layers one by one based on a time function, say every 2 seconds.

To show or hide a layer:

```
map.setLayoutProperty("layerId", "visibility", "visible");
map.setLayoutProperty("layerId", "visibility", "none");
```

To make animation smoother, you should also use:

```
map.setPaintProperty("layerId", "raster-opacity", opacity);
```

Here's a codepen with working example similar to rainviewer:

https://codepen.io/manishraj/full/gOYKMjO

Comment: I tried your solution, but it doesn't work well, there are glitches, and the radar disappears and appears every time.

Answer (score 0):

You could run a `setInterval` function to update your URL, similar to how it is done in [this example](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/animate-images/). Yours would look something like:

```
setInterval(function() {
   map.getSource("rainviewer").updateImage({ url: getPath(data[data.length - 1]) });
}, 200);
```

Comment: "updateImage" function, just work with image not with my endpoint url